# Solving an ODE with a Power Series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was working out the following ODE about the point x = 0:

$y''+ x^2 y' + x^2y = 0$

I can get to the characteristic equation: $2a_2 +6a_3x + \sum_{i=2}^\infty [(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}+(n-1)+a_{n-2}]x^n$

But I can't seem to see how this turns into a series.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that you are missing a $a_{n-1}$ in your equation, but that is probably a typo.

Remember that $y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, and thus we have that $y(0)=y_0 = a_0$ and $y'(0)=v_0=a_1$. Hence we know $a_0$ and $a_1$ from out initial conditions.

Now we make use of the equation:
\begin{align*}
 2a_2 + 6a_3 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty\left[(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+(n-1)a_{n-1} +a_{n-2} \right]x^n=0
\end{align*}
This happens if:
\begin{align*}
 &2a_2 =0 \Leftrightarrow a_2=0\\
 &6a_3 =0 \Leftrightarrow a_3 =0\\
 &\left[(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+(n-1)a_{n-1} +a_{n-2} \right] =0, \quad \mbox{ for } n\in \{2,3,\ldots \}.
\end{align*}

Lets start by calculating $a_4$ (by setting $n=2$):
\begin{align*}
 4\cdot 3a_4 + a_1+a_0=0\\
 12a_4 + v_0+y_0=0\\
 a_4 = -\frac{1}{12}(v_0+y_0)
\end{align*}

In principle we may continue this process to get sa many coeficients as we like. If lucky/clever we may see a pattern to get all coeficients - but sadly that is a rather rare case. So usually we get some approximation - and if we're good an estimate on the error.

Hope this was what you had in mind.

**Addition:**
Since the ODE is linear one can solve the two cases $(y_0,v_0)=(1,0)$ and $(y_0,v_0)=(0,1)$ as any other solution is a linear combination of these. Now that you have fixed values for $a_0$ and $a_1$ it's easy to write a program to canculate hundreds of coefficients - if thats your thing ;o)